# PGFPlots colormap increase number of discrete colours

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

Consider this MWE:

[image]

I have 32 plots, and I want the colormap to be distributed evenly across all the plots. At the moment, after 9 plots, the colours cycle back to the start. Is there any way to increase the number of discrete colours used by the colormap? I thought maybe `cycle list/Oranges-32` would work, but no.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        cycle list/Oranges,
    ]
    \foreach \X in {1,...,32}{%
        \addplot {rnd-\X};
    }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `colors of colormap` from p. 220 of the manual can help here. Of course you can replace `hot` by whatever you like and adjust the step size.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colormap name=hot,%colorbar,
    cycle list={[colors of colormap={0,30,...,1000}]}]
    \foreach \X in {1,...,32}{%
        \addplot {rnd-\X};
    }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]